# Cancel all inertia/bounce animations on UIScrollView on event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uianimation

I've got a UIScrollView that has inertia/bounce enabled. This is desirable so long as the user hasn't tapped any UI elements, but if they do, the actions don't perform the selector until after the bounce/inertia has stopped.

I'd like to cancel all animations on the scroll view as soon as the user touches another element. I tried

```
[scrollView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

in the tap action's selector, but that didn't have any effect (presumably because the selector doesn't fire until after the animation has ended). How can I instantly stop all inertia/bounce on the scroll view from another method?

**Edit:** putting a break point in the selector actually does fire `removeAllAnimations` immediately. So maybe I just have the wrong layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the animations didn't do the trick, but forcing the content offset without an animation did:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
```